# sobrepor texto em background

Tags: html, css

Como eu faço para colocar metade do texto em cima do background azul?

```css
.event_background {
 background: #bdecef;
}
.flexbox_grid {
 display: flex;
}
.flexbox_event_image {
   width: 70.0%;
   margin: 1%;
}
.flexbox_event_description {
 width: 30.0%;
   margin: 1%; 
}
.flexbox_event_cort {
    width: 700px;
 height: 350px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.flexbox_event_cort img {
   width: auto;
}
.event_align {
 padding-top: 40px;
}
.event_data {
 font: 600 12px/18px "b";
 font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.event_day{
 margin-right: 8px;
    font: 400 16px/18px Ubuntu Condensed;
    color: #ee5949;
    font-style: italic;
}
.event_title h4 {
 position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #0c2044;
    font: 700 30px/30px "b";
    font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox_grid">
 <div class="flexbox_event_image event_background">
  <div class="flexbox_event_cort">
   <img  src="https://guia-static.gazetadopovo.com.br/materias/repositorio/1503068879.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="flexbox_event_description event_align">
  <div class="event_data"><span class="event_day">Domingo</span> 22-10-2017</div>
  <div class="event_title"><h4>Villa Mix</h4></div>
  <div class="event_title"><h4>Exprotrade Pinhais</h4></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Desta forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "colocar metade do texto em cima do background azul?" Como assim ? Só vejo um fundo com uma imagem

Comment: Subi uma imagem, é daquela forma

Answer (score 0):

Para atingir esse efeito precisa de:

- Não aplicar uma dimensão tão grande de largura na imagem (pelo menos aqui no snippet)
- Retirar as margens de cada div dentro do `flex` para que eles fiquem juntos
- Aplicar cor de fundo e espaçamento à esquerda no div com os textos

É importante mencionar que a soma das larguras deve ser 100%, e tanto `padding`, `margin` e `border` contam para essa largura.

Exemplo:

```css
.event_background {
  background: #bdecef;
}

.flexbox_grid {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox_event_image {
  width: 65%; /*agora 65%*/
  /*margin: 1%;*//*sem margin*/
}

.flexbox_event_description {
  width: 35%;
  background-color:#73d8e8; /*azul de fundo*/
  padding-left:5%; /*padding 5% aqui para que as letras nao fiquem coladas a esquerda*/
  /*margin: 1%;*//*sem margin*/
}

.flexbox_event_cort {

  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexbox_event_cort img {
  width: auto;
}

.event_align {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.event_data {
  font: 600 12px/18px "b";
  font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.event_day {
  margin-right: 8px;
  font: 400 16px/18px Ubuntu Condensed;
  color: #ee5949;
  font-style: italic;
}

.event_title h4 {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0c2044;
  font: 700 30px/30px "b";
  font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox_grid">
  <div class="flexbox_event_image event_background">
    <div class="flexbox_event_cort">
      <img src="https://guia-static.gazetadopovo.com.br/materias/repositorio/1503068879.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox_event_description event_align">
    <div class="event_data"><span class="event_day">Domingo</span> 22-10-2017</div>
    <div class="event_title">
      <h4>Villa Mix</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="event_title">
      <h4>Exprotrade Pinhais</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Se quiser centrar os textos na `<div>` da direita basta adicionar `text-align:center` ao seletor `.event_title h4` e ao `.event_data`